# rostopic pub multiarray

Tags: ros, multiarray, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quick question, how do I publish a multiarray? I use rostopic a lot, and its tremendously helpful. One thing I was never able to figure out, was how publish a multiarray(I also wasn't able to find a post on it).

This is the format it provides:

```
rostopic pub /topic_name std_msgs/Float32MultiArray "layout:
  dim:
  - label: ''
    size: 0
    stride: 0
  data_offset: 0
data:
- 0"
```

That can publish a single element multiarray, but I couldn't figure out how to add another element on that array.

I've tried...

```
rostopic pub /topic_name std_msgs/Float32MultiArray "layout:
  dim:
  - label: ''
    size: 0
    stride: 0
  data_offset: 0
data:
- [0.0, 1.0]"
```

and a bunch of other variants, but nothing works. If someone can help with the syntax, that would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189073/rostopic-pub-multiarray/) by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/10244/publish-arrays-to-a-topic-on-the-command-line/):

```
$ rostopic pub /topic_name std_msgs/Float32MultiArray "layout:
dim:
  - label: ''
    size: 0
    stride: 0
  data_offset: 0
data: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]"
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [atomoclast](https://answers.ros.org/users/26451/atomoclast/) on 2016-09-13**:
Hello, I tried this a Int16MultiArray message and got this error out:

```
ERROR: No field name [dim]

Args are: [layout.dim layout.data_offset data]
```

Any idea what it could be?

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-03-26**:
@atomoclast: Your message is malformed. You need to put dim inside the layout key, like this answer shows. e.g. `{layout: {dim: [...]}, ...}`, not `{dim: [...]}`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@atomoclast

i have an Messege Generated with works

```
 rostopic pub /speed std_msgs/Int16MultiArray "layout:
   dim: []
   data_offset: 0
 data: [10, 100]"
```

the Importen part ist the make an multi line CMD, and not convert the input to an single line

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-26**:
YAML strings can be mulit-line or single-line. http://wiki.ros.org/YAML%20Overview

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me none of this worked, I always have an error like
"field data[] must be an integer type" (or a float if it's a float array of course.).

How I achieved to send multiple value was to set one value a a line preceding by a hyphen.

exemple:

```
rostopic pub /modbus_wrapper/input std_msgs/Int32MultiArray "layout:
  dim:
  - label: ''
    size: 2
    stride: 0
  data_offset: 0
data:
- 0 
- 1
- 3
"
```

---

Originally posted by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) with karma: 15 on 2017-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1